# Display Advanced Custom Fields on Woocommerce shop and product category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

In Woocommerce, I an using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin, creating some custom fields on my products.

How can I display this custom fields (eg: `grad1` and `grad2`) on shop and product category archive pages?

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Thank you @RossAlexander I use the text field type, only want to show them on shop and category page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will display your ACF fields on shop and category archives (no need to change any template):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'acf_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function acf_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    if ( $grad1  = get_field('grad1', $product->get_id()) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'. __("Grad 1") . '</strong>: ' . $grad1 . '</p>';
    }

    if ( $grad2  = get_field('grad1', $product->get_id()) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'. __("Grad 2") . '</strong>: ' . $grad2 . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.